# How to get the value of unique primary key id immediately after insertion

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a sqlite table named as 'TX_TABLE' and the primary key Id name is TX_UID.
I insert a row into this table and would like to get the value of this unique id column 'TX_UID". How to get it?

```
db.insert(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, null, contentvalues);
String td = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
helper.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the Android [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) class, the insert() call returns the row id directly:

> public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues
>   values)
>
> Returns the row ID of the newly
>   inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

Comment: how to get the value of that row ID?

Comment: `long rowID = db.insert(...`

Comment: Thanks Joop. It helped me. A simple answer for new entrants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) (click on function name for details) to get the last inserted id.

From documentation:

> The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function

It is possible to retrieve it using the following sql command

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```